# Jquery lightbox doesn't extend downward

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

I'm trying to implement a lightbox in a website I'm building and it works but for some reason does not extend down when the user scrolls down on the page.

Here is the JS/JQuery:

```
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
var $image = $("<img>");

$overlay.append($image);

$("body").append($overlay);

$('#imageGallery a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $href = $(this).attr("href");
  $image.attr("src", $href);
  $overlay.show();
});

$overlay.click(function(){
  $overlay.hide();
});
```

And here's the relevant CSS:

```
#overlay {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
}

#overlay img {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
```

The issue could be some kind of conflict with other CSS, but I figured I'd ask if there's something glaring I'm missing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:fixed` to overlay, instead absolute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

About `fixed` value:

> Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page.